# Notepad++ Replace all with an exception

Tags: regex, replace, notepad++

I am attempting to edit a csv file, below is a sample line from this file.

```
|MIGRATE|;|10000|;|2ACC0003|;|30/09/13|;|Positive Adjmt.|;||;|MIGRATE|;|95004U
```

The beginning of the line |MIGRATE| needs to be modified without changing the second MIGRATE so the line would read

```
|MIGRATE|;|MIG_IN|;|10000|;|2ACC0003|;|30/09/13|;|Positive Adjmt.|;||;|MIGRATE|;|95004U
```

There are 7700 or so lines so if I am forced to do this manually I will probably cry a little.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Just replace all the ones you want not changed with another word temporarily, then replace the rest with what you want. I'm not sure what you're asking here, but from what I can guess this might help.

Comment: Problem resolved!!! Thanks! I was trying to just replace the first.. Didn't consider that which is so much easier!

Comment: Glad I could help. If you are confident this solved the problem, I'd appreciate it if you could mark my answer as the answer by clicking the check under the vote score.

Answer (score 0):

You can use beginning of line anchors:

Find:

```
^(\|MIGRATE\|)
```

Replace with:

```
$1;|MIG_IN|
```

[regex101 demo](http://regex101.com/r/gF8oW1)

Just make sure that you are using the regular expression mode of the Search&Replace.

---

If you want to be a bit fancier, you can use a positive lookbehind:

Find:

```
(?<=^\|MIGRATE\|)
```

Replace with:

```
;|MIG_IN|
```

---

`^` Will match only at the beginning of a line.

`( ... )` is called a capture group, and will save the contents of the match in variable you can use (in the first regex, I accessed the variable using `$1` in the replace. The first capture gets stored to `$1`, the second to `$2`, etc.)

`|` is a special character meaning 'or' in regex (to match a character or group of characters or another, e.g. `a|b` matches `a` or `b`. As such, you need to escape it with a backslash to make a regex match a literal `|`.

In my second regex, I used `(?<= ... )` which is called a positive lookbehind. It makes sure that the part to be matched has what's inside before it. For instance, `(?<=a)b` matches a `b` only if it has an `a` before it. So that the `b` in `ab` matches but not in `bb`.

The website I linked also explains the details of the regex and you can try out some regex yourself!

Comment: Thanks. I have done this now. But this regex is something I really could do with knowing. This sort of thing needs doing quite a bit.

Comment: @SinrG If you have any more questions on that particular topic/problem, I'll be glad to help! And if the answer worked for you, you can mark it as accepted by clicking on the tick outline next to the answer to get some points :)

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you could just search for Just search for:

```
^\|MIGRATE\|
```

And replace with:

```
|MIGRATE|;|MIG_IN|
```

Make sure you've checked 'Regular expression' in the 'Search Mode' options.

Explanation: The `^` is a begin anchor; it will match the beginning of the line, ensuring that it does not match the second `|MIGRATE|`. The `\` characters are required to escape the `|` characters since they normally have special meaning in regular expressions, and you want to match a literal `|`.